# Pedir dato al usuario autoejecutable

Tags: r

Quiero pedir un dato al usuario:

```
   library(svDialogs)
    
    codigo <- dlgInput(message="Introduzca código")$res
    
    data1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 1:5)
    
    write.csv2(data1, "data1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Si lo ejecuto desde Rstudio funciona sin problemas, me pide el dato.

Si creo un .bat para hacer el script autoejecutable

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\Rscript.exe" --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\prueba\script.R" quit
```

Me guarda el csv en el escritorio, pero no me pide el dato.

Answer (score 0):

La única forma que encontré que puede hacer funcionar el acceso a la `gui` desde  un script, es invocarlo de esta forma:

```
R.exe --vanilla --ess < script.r
```

La diferencia es el uso de `R.exe` en vez de `Rscript.exe`, el parámetro `--ess` y la redirección `<`.

> –ess (Windows only) Set Rterm up for use by R-inferior-mode in ESS,
> including asserting interactive use (without the command-line editor)
> and no buffering of stdout.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe" --vanilla --interactive --ess  "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\01-prueba_autoejecutable\script.R"
ATENCIN: opcin desconocida '--interactive'

Comment: si pongo interactive()  en R me sale TRUE

Comment: Estoy con la versión  de R 4.1.2 que es inferior a la tuya y `--interactive` es un parámetro valido, tendría que ver si puedo actualizar de versión y probar, cualquier cosa  te digo.

Comment: Con la versión 4.3.1 hay que quitar el parámetro `--interactive` , prueba con `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\R.exe" --vanilla --ess "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\01-prueba_autoejecutable\script.R"`

Comment: Ya lo estuve probando y nada. Pantalla en negro de Rterm con línea final de "Escriba q() pasa salir de R".  A las malas hacer un txt con el código y que R lea el txt,. En vez de pedirlo por pantalla habrá q modificar el txt.

Comment: Lamento tener que decir que en mi maquina funciona, igual no fue fácil hacerlo , estoy probando con un Windows 10 y un  `cmd.exe` estándar (no powershell). Una alternativa es ir a la GUI natural de R que es Shiny, sino podrías probar otros paquetes  tipo: https://rgg.r-forge.r-project.org/

Comment: Yo tengo Windows 10 Enterprise. He leído que desde R portable puede que funcione, pero es que no puedo instalar nada en el ordenador del trabajo, por lo que no puedo probarlo.